# How to use switch case in reactjs to show different components based on routing path

Tags: reactjs, jsp

I have to develop a concept like based on routing path, I need to show the component in the same tab. I thought this concept can be done using switch-case by taking routing path.

If any other way is there you can suggest me.

Comment: You can have state in component and different components will be there as `{this.state.route === "one" && <Comp1 />}`.

Comment: Bahunya, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer - sure - will do. I can understand why technical style is preferred.